# Android XMLRPC Fault Code

Tags: android, rpc, xml-rpc, fault

We have been using XMLRPC for android and it was working well until we got our hands dirty with Base64 encoding for byte[] (images) -- (we did base64_string.replace("/","$$") for transmission). We have tried undoing the changes and its looking like an XMLRPC error.

We are getting the following error in the DDMS:

```
06-10 23:27:02.970: DEBUG/Test(343): org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCFault: XMLRPC Fault:  [code 0]
06-10 23:27:02.970: DEBUG/Test(343):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient.callEx(XMLRPCClient.java:308)
06-10 23:27:02.970: DEBUG/Test(343):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCMethod.run(XMLRPCMethod.java:33)
```

Just before this I checked the body (xml message -- which is perfect) and the response received:

```
06-10 23:27:02.940: INFO/System.out(343): Response received: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@437762f8
```

Since the message is not even reaching our cloud, the issue is mostly with XMLRPC for android.

Any help will be most appreciated. Thanks

Best
Sameer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a little bit: We must supply the byte[] directly to the params object which will call the Base64 on its own (don't mess with your own implementation of Base64 -- else you will not be able to retrieve it as a byte[] on the server).

We are however stuck here: A corrupted xml message... Any ideas will be most appreciated!

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>OperationClass.getProfile</methodName>
    <paramsX0xWNiGh6F /
        D8hfs2GIhLlHM2LIkrVeUqXdGIiKajrdt6CF78SiMF4IspC +
        XhNTBLFhHNyAImyGq1DwbhsrwK +
        aspCedKWLmSWLKKZmEsmrN8BcM7xmHMA7oPN0TS9r8Jky7J5HbwRJJqFuQTgK56POwdTO6H8 /
        UzY38QsxEAHAK4rf78dqRxERJNaQG96tm1cPD1 /
        Lcqf0sOmaKIyLWHGFV2HaTnttvdP9uU + FiWai7Bf4KRpLN22>
        <param>
            <value>
                <struct>
                    <member>
                        <name>GroupNo</name>
                        <TlFY8tai / ADcQM6SxQQdRHlZwkwX / Ah + FblDcJYNbsL +
                            XwXerJ8jkjNm9ayURLtGCzpZoKoVmsA99C / JXU7value>
                            <string>1</string>
            </value>
        </member>
            <member>
                <name>EM825ewD2L+UbvH228Lf2QyYvxoCMKA3RTNBAgentID</name>
                <value>
                    <string>9.9006796E7</string>
                </value>
            </member>
            B1EaFzAu8EoxZza0WlKz9Rg2A5ZJ+m1La/JpwGOQKBcrhA28sw3CWv/vtgvC4zbIb41ZOlViNiwJm6KJ0lpA
            <member>
                <name>endTime</name>
                <value>
                    <string>2010-06-11
                        01:08:5z9keYptVvgmt/3eX1gy4jlFY6q2mAAzox+Cs7pyJIrsAd7Km3e0xgBsALsFc1</string>
                </value>
            </member>
            <member>
                <name>
                    Name
                </namec7rtHcfzDlFeK90grv7fbY3w2A04ICtX34X997qaslAjNNCbomdx0hJFtICZOuQbdI9gphktHa+7gr74iq0SWB3pwzfC4>
                    <value>
                        <string>Tulsi Das</string>
                    </value>
            </member>
            <member>
                <name>7U8vRwMk5+S01FKtKZozk8nCqdPrXcf/gmdOivIN9RaHKpCC/kORrKAPD+YNZD8SAH4ZspCBaCdtLPpPyKayALongitude</name>
                <value>
                    <string>0</string>
                </value>
            </member>
            <member>
                <name>tempId</name>
                <value>
                    <string>1.2762e+12</string>
                </LA2/Cv8fYNvNu0IFx1Lfgq7B/aNahKWzWJNZC8SIPsSh+0pB2DpX82opRWMF2KPsH3FsJUurSW1WpJ/YM+zZPaYBjWQPLRot4gpR2Ds53UTzTCZfg1OT9C2Ou8NtW1WtIArvalue>
            </member>
            <member>
                <name>startTime</name>
                NbjudrC6TVc3GtxHvbf6GnKQgWiHYNPwe4QIl99mpyvT1QGqRZcLekL9r
                <value>
                    <string>2010-06-11 01:07:47</string>
                </value>
                1wSTVo1kDyUnPTjjYnkVnaiNwW8GtyDl3r3SVVFqrUwv5hdxNwaLR
            </member>
            <member>
                <name>AgentName</name>
                mA9ZA8lFzANaOwQ0qH0VJNJJvf++tSOWxnctVGjoAa5c2JYQ1kDxIJ1ibsEwhaQOymKWNyG4
                <value>
                    <string>Kaveriamma</string>
                </valueFd3/vEeImuLElDqrSe7B/4UPmh2rLFjYBykrj1JYNy4ZZ2oj>
            </member>
            <member>
                <name>
                    CenterNo</8+QTfqZucbWname>
                    <value>
                        <string>101</string>
                    </value>
                </memberzTJqv0FOEuymvhtTbggKwcSAG4>
                    <member>
                        <name>LanpgWxtWMwxoCzN3B6QbsPM1CFgZ9y5BN8U63R21rKUh1tBaShX/od5TU5ICutGrNh2WiDAqdsRnMlp2dAplz4BN/ryUo3kwDcwguage</name>
                        <value>
                            <string>English</string>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>Addressv7F9xmAtasBB2Tlai4BWBuQNWVLTN8E9QzIlIJP8E29oEmL</name>
                        <value>
                            <string>Bangalore</string>
                        </valueGQTgUAOwdmnZTDggKx3p964xzZs2IGuqgKeNwvb>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>Lattitude</name>
                        <value>
                            <string>0</string>
                        </Z3ocZzCj1t3XN24dgpjkaZgG523EDcwznkEDJNhWpOmMyYLlwQFZ+WsSvFaYkHYNTfd6Q66Me4mxvalue>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>
                            Profession
                        </Atr02b2apL2kcSE7Bt1N9AJ5yVOxaeO2aL/i5azGv3yNFLfg6xteEbdv/s+yrname>
                            <value>
                                <string>Salaried</string>
                            </value>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>Image1</name>
                        <valueIYsZxeO6QZzqnBiq +
                            gA8dQ1VG5CVuo9hjrRBd7WKXQvurAC8AuADTBOQuy2nGgvl6wL04yjH63HV1ygp3Ze2BGFfDbhoem7mFoBT1IJtpgzIhzDTRWqaTkbhLKAPusq1K6Pqa5R0YQpdM +
                            Ci6XmRfouab4akWnDKwWdTBeTtvuOYNxiULynZ0gbmxi1XVQfgmAu0PxLei01o8c0hG9YurRbcpCvWGS2AGwD2ELZ2vMHZ6U4MyvOiNT0 /
                            Qt433lUHYOlCPEVfwFp4rw1MfmKKZ44BWJsXnOsUrBYmID9G + IDcbR /
                            BBOfbMAH6Ok5rztsblcnV9Jx75afqACz9MO1E75cqOxGdJf0OV1MWKgJtbnqTrlhevoPpgnCfjfOPy1J6PoZqA3CK0bBaLYQDs>
                            <base64>
                                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
                            </base64YGggX4SHmG6ObkLmJpLnwvm7vaXSN9HJbU8+DQtMgCfcgWER/A/b/sE4lA3ctKMjG6glVZD9smY>
                            </value>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>Image2</name>
                        <valueFpo21mMWTc8AR0GG5NuMukGd8yyHpKPU +
                            n8eId5d8BLAWzDrWw8JxCmnSYTOghUj3aDkGkwQfIa43 +
                            kCekDoE3y3XYHfMXWIcce6Nod2 + ZMCtKx5wRrywzejVyWpDgCOqw +
                            fWico4lRb2zym1pmj9Pylzvl5C / wUdNgD + AsALCcorDaJ09>
                            <base64>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA4AAAAWCAIAAAB/rzpwAAAAA3NeO2wvNStX7ZUhDG6q7R0h8ODb6dBUwmtimDsHTzv3seaXmiYw3GWitlOELcJQ+T4wjosLQ7u9R3nVNr4X9BXwmP7U7CHPp/lugfiH8B4F8CSVQFBgUzC42AAAACXElEQVQokVWSMWskRxCFv106qIYx9MAKtuEEN+BgR1xwuswK/RN8of+K/4Izj7s2DVBaXVnheqgAs1eCmvlHVxiCEPBZXcNeGhwbhPgOspAGjMX73BeSYs8EMK35DT16yW6DfaNua+jqku2vb544U2uElhlWmxHBKDo/ghOeChV7QQjfcQj9Qgx2swHIFFRTU94pXb5GfMs5M4EzInABaABkmBMhhyKmwXEOtuS+3QWpLnC7b6fu7/i8A/zhC2bR+PZdWeF6qACx9v1MuBB87ICxgRuSHDMLaMWCr1WoDRpuen6cvvZ+tEr/R+nX0DlrFZRzzrqQiYePKxk10lWwd45shdkVK8/63rP2w+mHovv9uE0vj4/0MBjjv+qHLY8deeXv/U23qze52bXrXnYnfOzvMAT0NaTRw7ItLCj7BoNT+n64p8efw/31/imkXdmiF9/UJorktIaP9MpPaSrN+8vXsV0yGDL2nIICMvHW8A7g2guTJ+u9/p93n9cd0EqNJbeeQRgFoNFHNKcNWWS2TAkdFw8xTauC9p63J3i/znXlffsG4avCa2jXcamrbMqbr1lnfrmUFZ8CSRikqupu+fChKKNVWIQjRcgzv5102B7DE1eH1WI/EcLkOV7WZd4BiN47rH6Nd9Z0PoQcWfzu7IZM4GfZA38L9C1fd+uAOxqem4ilnWoBYB/DuB/w/83vodpckq3wvuNCcCpBmAuYPpbpe/w7cDvpx2LY/t9fbgWd/CdLSHN5dZupKSgvcE0LVANZp7tyia3O+Ca+C7S0G2lLX8nke6s25O/a03PpfX/LNB+mGAJNOiqTEaWUsAoSfddbZ+YslRRDdB5A5qy0TDMccTVABcIqADQ8HlhCLUXTbsb5cmR7c/fLr9fzXvFVpEETUFsFHM7PD3PKNR2mPgTMhs2YpXIoYRVwRsM7/+xAVZ0+Tbd/TuGsj+eDPxt/ClPoLEjShdQnuUJuARgwF2qtqT9kcNBG4McKCK4g7Moh3yjP1QbhaV1lU0yT5JQjC6njPsWcsNqs0e/Ck8a8v80n9BRXevX23f9R605cW6tc9wp5Kf2bTwzxuhhdUqpmF2Pdm8+fJN4Zo4/naOlMp0n+3LtJjDp0B25vbeXMu6wdqUGK25r+T+n78D4Bj+v3XIxR3GBNEcAzDgPndCBEdtymDszFCvKGXZQK/5S91dPou/aLMQQk6T1M77WWS7kjAP7LT6LipQw5Jb0jH1j4T9G6SdchTKAsC/Q7/f+x7GBxOppcUniOZ8/mvBIUQNTRp4lepYB7NDFATgIQxfjuWUkIIy0rGgVN/5lMpQjoWHUsuSZBTlnSiLk+egV2+vSw56Sg1AI+nyff9vJufbz1tnNdOUQsNX8tbm/vpUoLYVuiJtE7WaqlC6nyUhfTOkXw1z0SczRbWMvyKlJd+RSP9UG9TS/A+az/A/0+81vY/g5NyaI+DkPOuSKcWQjr1TofM9gzte/6dEgqSocUV7Ec9n0XcDZ9nj/cbOMqhtCflBf1KZ9CDqiRD2n7x/ZivBg2Q+gCzyWwRf2n0sDxotvpn/C/+b+JrV4Ak3lH5wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==</base64>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                </I5hyAAb15dkwQ1mpkKbv6dSteAAAPeklEQVRBXFMYdwdladeXxvM9G8d7jvk+tBuE2s773hrIXwyF03dd29LnBkvNmtJWctOzZAl9MJEUUIbkBa45ALsGZQ1ZY1sLCjmMwO9z0yHV4vs2obsC/9CWOa0Fsstruct>
                </value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>
```